# $index used in name attribute of textarea lopped through ng-repeat returns with $index as string in the directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ckeditor

My Textarea HTML:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(key, contents) in growthEnvData.product_features" class="tile-inner tile-fixed">
<textarea  placeholder="Enter Product Pricing" class="form-placeholder features" ng-model="contents.features" rows="1" style="height:150px;" name="features-{{$index}}" ></textarea>
</div>
```

Angular JS Directive:

```
app.directive('ckEditorInline', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

            var eleName = attr.name;
            var ck = CKEDITOR.inline(eleName);

            if (!ngModel) return;
            ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            });
            function updateModel() {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
            });
        }
        ck.on('change', updateModel);
        ck.on('key', updateModel);
        ck.on('dataReady', updateModel);

        ngModel.$render = function (value) {
            ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
        };
    }
};
```

When I get attr.name in the directive it returns features-{{$index}} instead of features-0. I want it to be features-0. How to do this? Please help.

Comment: Kindly provide a working Fiddle to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.directive('ckEditorInline', function ($timeout) {
return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {


        $timeout(function(){
            var ck = CKEDITOR.inline(elm[0]);

            if (!ngModel) return;
            ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            });
            function updateModel() {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            }
            ck.on('change', updateModel);
            ck.on('key', updateModel);
            ck.on('dataReady', updateModel);

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };                
        }, 2000);
    }
```

};
});

I tried running the code after 2 seconds by setting timeout as a quick fix and it is working fine now. If you have any alternate solution please let me know.
The issues is with initializing multiple inline ckeditor in single page.